# Control if a 3x3 matrix is in an N x N Matrix with N>=3

Tags: java, arrays, scala, matrix, multidimensional-array

Here is an example of what I mean.

I got two multidimensional arrays w and z.
z is a 3x3 matrix.
Now I want to controll if z is part of the bigger multidimensional array w.
Like z= (1,2,3),
        (1,2,3),
        (1,2,3)

w= (4,7,1,2,3)
   (7,8,1,2,3)
   (9,0,1,2,3)
   (8,1,5,3,6)
   (4,6,6,6,6)

In that case my function would give me a true.
I know how to acess all elements and single rows and columns.
Could someone give me a little push in the right direction?
My try

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Omg, SO community is so rude. The question looks clear to me, he just needs a push. @richmolt you could scan `w` elements (using 3 nested for loops) looking for the first element of `z`. Once you find it, start a secondary scan routine that checks if every other `z` element matches in `w` (considering the coordinates of the first match as offset). If they do, return true. As soon as any element doesn't, stop the secondary scan and continue the primary one

Comment: Yeah, where your try?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that return 1 if sub matrix of order 3x3 exist , else returns 0.

```
int submatrixcheck(int a[][10],int b[3][3],int n)
{
    int i,j,k,l,p=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if( (a[i][j] == b[0][0]) && i<(n-4) && (j<n-4))
            {
                for(k = 0;k<3;k++)
                    for(l= 0;l<3;l++)
                        if(a[i+k][j+l]!=b[k][l])
                        {
                            p=1;
                            goto c;
                        }

                if(p==0)
                   return 1;
                c:
            }
    return 0;

}
```